# How to consume secured OData service in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, odata

I am trying to consume an SAP Odata service in angularJS, but I am not getting how to add credentials of that Odata service.

Here is my code:

```
$http.post("url" , {
    username: "*****",
    password: "*****"
}, {
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function (response){
alert(response);

});
```

I am getting 401 Un Authorization Error.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to communicate with SAP Gateway (OData service), it is easiest to use basic authentication. It is enabled by default.

In order to make service calls from Angular using basic authentication, you need to encode the credentials first:

```
var encoded = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
```

Once you have encoded the credentials, you will need to add an Authorization header to your requests:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
```

Once you have set the header, you can start sending your requests as per usual, e.g.:

```
$http.get('http://sap.machine.net/service/odata.svc/contacts')
        .success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Alternatively, you could pass the authentication details in every call, e.g.:

```
$http.get('http://sap.machine.net/service/odata.svc/contacts', {.
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded }
        }).success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: How secure is this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 return this.http.get<Response>(this.baseURL + apiURL, { withCredentials: true })
.pipe(
  retry(1),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```